# Integrate Mobile Push App with whole account

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

Is there a way to integrate SFMC Mobile Push SDK to make your app avalible for all BUs on acccount? From my understanding when I create an app key in app enter it links to one BU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  As of today there is no way to link the application created in AppCenter to multiple BUs.  Please contact your account manager and make a feature request.